# IE 11 on Windows 7 with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does `IE 11` has support with `selenium webdriver` on windows 7? 
I tried it on my windows 7 machine. My IE driver instance opens but URL not opens.

Error appears below:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: On the whole, Selenium does not support IE11. However, for us to help properly, you will need to give us more information. This needs to the version of IEDriver, the version of Selenium, the full stack trace of your error and a copy of the code where that error happens.

Comment: Just to make this more visible, and save people the time I wasted, **Unofficial IE11 support has been broken since mid December**. See https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/selenium-users/TdY_rRNF-gw

Answer (score 6):

For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`.

For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`.

Please note that the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a `DWORD` value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of `0`.

References -
1. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/featurebfcache-in-ie11/b461e166-c1e0-4171-be93-aec65e9de727

2. https://leaptest.com/support/knowledgebase/configuration-of-ie-for-using-selenium-web-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, it was just released:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069

Comment: How does it work with Selenium? My understanding is that this is for the w3c testing proposal, which is what Selenium 3 will be based on. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think "released" might be a stretch.

Comment: This is just the web driver that lets you right your basic driver commands that will get executed. You then register a node that has IE11 and Selenium should take care of the rest.